# What is the Quickest Way to Check If All Values in an Array Are Numeric?

Tags: php, arrays

I must check big arrays to see if they are 100% filled with numeric values.
The only way that comes to my mind is foreach and then is_numeric for every value, but is that the fastest way?

Comment: *Any* solution to this problem will loop over the array values. Whether you need to do it in code or a function does that for you is another question, but in both cases there is a loop. So I guess the performance should be pretty much the same, regardless of what you do.

Comment: What about validating the values before they get into the array ?

Comment: It is not that simple because the values come into and go from the array in random ways and some of them can be null or false or "" , and then I must do calculations with them, and result of these calculations must be null if some of the data in the array is not numeric.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

assuming your array is one-dimensional and just made up of integers:

```
return ctype_digit(implode('',$array));
```

Comment: Had to undo my vote, `false` and `NULL` values, which return false for `is_numeric()` are imploded as empty strings here, escaping `ctype_digit()`.

Comment: @BoltClock: OP assures the array is "100% filled with numeric values"

Comment: I think implode operation is rather costly in time.

Comment: @user393087: if you can back up your claim that implode is expensive, your "i think" comment has no basis. real coders say "i checked". that's why benchmarking is a science.

Comment: Beware, an unexpected behavior could make your life difficult: 
`ctype_digit(5) -> false `

Integers smaller than 255 are interpreted as ASCII characters.

Answer (score 11):

Filter the array using is_numeric. If the size of the result is the same as the original, then all items are numeric:

```
$array = array( 1, '2', '45' );
if ( count( $array ) === count( array_filter( $array, 'is_numeric' ) ) ) {
    // all numeric
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
array_map("is_numeric", array(1,2,"3","hello"))

Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => )
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is rather old, but I'm using Andy's approach in a current project of mine and find it to be the most reliable and versatile solution, as it works for all numerical values, negative, positive, and decimal alike.

Here's an average value function I wrote:

```
$array = [-10,1,2.1,3,4,5.5,6]; // sample numbers
function array_avg($arr) {
    if (is_array($arr) && count($arr) === count(array_filter($arr, 'is_numeric'))) {
        return array_sum($arr)/count($arr);
    } else {
        throw new Exception("non-numerical data detected");
    }
}
echo array_avg($array); // returns 1.6571428571429
```

Answer (score -2):

This small function works fine for me

```
function IsNumericarr($arr){
    if(!is_array($arr)){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        foreach($arr as $ar){
            if(!is_numeric($ar)){
                return false;
                exit;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Loop is needed

Answer (score -2):

```
if(array_reduce($array, function($c, $v){return $c & (int)is_numeric($v);}, 1))
```

Comment: This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.  An explanation would help this answer become more like a Stack Overflow answer.

Answer (score -3):

The quickest way might be to just assume they're all numerals and continue on with your operation. If your operation fails later on, then you know something isn't a numeral. But if they are all actually numerals... you can't get much faster than O(0)!

Comment: But some non-numeric values will slip through because of weaktyping/autocasting.  The assumption is not safe.